# C programming Segmentation fault , To Huge number?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I have a question about my program.

I am getting a compiler error : **Segmentation fault**

Always, if the computed number is about 19 digits, I am getting the error above.

Do I need another data type or it is just the huge number ?

Code below :

```
// calculates Fibonacci numbers

int main(void) {
    unsigned long long fibo[4000000] = {[0] = 0, [1] = 1}, i, j;
    for ( i = 2; i < 4000000; i++) {
        fibo[i] = fibo[i-1] + fibo[i-2];
    }
    for ( j = 0; j < 4000000; j++) {
        printf("%llu, ", fibo[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `unsigned long long fibo[4000000]` too big for stack.

Comment: does it mean the number  can't be higher than trillion ?

Comment: Why do you need an array? Fibonacci only needs to remember last term and last-but-one.

Comment: There is a stack size limit, on linux you can check with `ulimit -s`, nromally 8KB. On windows it's usually one 1MB I think.

Comment: @lordmaximus It depends on the stack size. Change to `static unsigned long long fibo[4000000]` or allocate by `malloc`.

Comment: `unsigned long long` will overflow ***way*** before you reach the 4000000th term. At term 94 heh heh.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your requests !

Comment: I just played around and tested it how far i can go, so i was wondering why the limit was at trillion